# Facebook login history

Tags: facebook, security, export, facebook-account

Can Facebook admins tell you an account's login history going further back in time than the most recent login?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Facebook Subpoena / Search Warrant Guidelines on cryptome](http://cryptome.org/isp-spy/facebook-spy.pdf), IP log data is generally retained for 90 days.  It is available for subpoenas and search warrants, for a cost ([$500 minimum](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17159)).

As for data that is available without a subpoena or search warrant, it seems that they will at least show you *unusual* login activity, see for example [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-do-i-view-facebook-review-recent-activity-window-and-why-cant-i-see-the-ip) and [this Facebook blog post](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=389991097130), as well as [this example of unusual account acitivity](http://anima.dudut.com/archives/recent-activity-log.html).

You can always see all of the sessions *currently logged in* to your account in **Account Settings** under **Account Security**.  If you enable Login Notifications then you can also see each of the different devices that have been used to log in to your account.  (See [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/facebook-last-login).)

Answer (score 1):

The information for all login activity for a Facebook account is saved. To access it simply so go your settings and there should be a link to "Download a copy of your Facebook data."

[How can I download my information from Facebook?](https://www.facebook.com/help/212802592074644) is a more detailed description of how to download your information.

and

[Accessing Your Facebook Data](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/405183566203254) shows what is included in the information downloaded.